# Create Wifi Hotspot for sharing SOCKS Proxy on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, socks, wifi-hotspot

I'm using Ubuntu Server and I have a SOCKS Proxy server on my client which is created with ssh -D command.
I want to create a Wifi Hotspot on this computer which passes the traffic through this SOCKS Proxy. I'm connected to Internet through ethernet, so Wifi is idle.

Is this possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Both TCP and UDP traffic and the rest (e.g. ICMP) dropped?

Answer (score 4):

TCP traffic from the hotspot can be passed through the `ssh -D` socks proxy using `redsocks`. With `redsocks` installed and configured one can use `iptables` to redirect all traffic from the wifi hotspot to `redsocks` which then passes it through the socks proxy.

For instance if your wifi hotspot is on the `10.42.0.1/24` subnet and the incoming `redsocks` port is `12345` issue:

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.42.0.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
```

For a detailed set of instructions visit http://abidmujtaba.blogspot.com/2016/07/ubuntu-create-wifi-hotspot-access-point.html

Comment: Is there a way to not have to run the `iptables` command every time?

Comment: iptables-save , google